# Loading numbers from Python dictionary

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to work this out by using a dictionary that has two different details:

```
direc = {}

a = 17
b = 165
direc.update({a: b})

a = 19
b = 174
direc.update({a: b})

for x,y in direc:
    print('age:' +str(x) + ' and height :'+str(y))
```

I need the output to be:

```
age:17 and height:165
age:19 and height:174
```

Comment: A directory? Do you mean a *dictionary*? Because you are using a dictionary. Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. This is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The {} is used to make a *dictionary* not a *directory*. Anyhow, to answer your question, you can save `a` and `b`as a *key* in direc. You can achieve that by:

```
direc={}

a=17
b=165
direc[a]= b

a=19
b=174
direc[a]= b

for x,y in direc.items(): # note: you need to use .items() it iterate through them
    print('age:' +str(x) + ' and height :'+str(y))
```

But this isn't the best way of saving age and height. Since if there's age two identical age, it will override the first. You should do it like:

```
direc["name"]=(a, b) # the name of the person
```

This way if you typed the person's name, it will return it's age and height.

```
direc={}

direc["personA"]= (17,165)  # you don't need to define a or b

direc["personB"]= (19,174)
for x,y in direc.items():
    print('name:' + str(x) + ', age:' +str(y[0]) + ' and height :'+str(y[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but now how can i split a dictionary to two different variable and print the, out

Comment: Neither of your two solutions work. Did you not test them?

Comment: @abccd Crashed with `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` and `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Much more simply, just give the initial directory value as a literal:

```
direc = {17: 165, 19: 174}
for age, ht in direc.items():
    print('age:', age, ' and height:', ht)
```

You don't have to build the dictionary one entry at a time.  Also, note that **print** allows you to supply a list of values -- you don't have to convert the numbers and concatenate them into the output line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `direc.items()` instead of `direc` (which just provides keys, not key+value pairs).

```
for x,y in direc.items():
    print('age:' +str(x) + ' and height :'+str(y))
```